# Нужно написать цикл, который предлагает пользователю ввести возраст и выводит цену билета

Tags: python

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как выйти из бесконечного цикла после ввода значения в input() . Подскажите пожалуйста

```
age = 'What is your age?'
age = int(input())


active = True    
print()
while active:
    #age = input(ticket)
    if age <= 3:
        print("price: 0$")
    elif age >= 3 and age <= 12:
        print("price: 10$")
    elif age > 12:
         print("price: 15$")
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос?

Comment: Не знаю как выйти из бесконечного цикла после ввода значения в input()

Comment: А почему нельзя просто убрать цикл while?

Comment: В вашем случае, чтобы выйти из бесконечного цикла, очевидно необходимо присвоить переменной active значение False.

Comment: Не понимаю зачем здесь вообще цикл?

Comment: Понимаю, но дело в том, что я не знаю как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Цикл является условием выполняемой задачи

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал вообще избавиться от цикла, т.к. он вообще не влияет на решение задачи:

```py
age = 'What is your age?'
age = int(input())   
print()
if age <= 3:
    print("price: 0$")
elif age > 3 and age <= 12:
    print("price: 10$")
elif age > 12:
     print("price: 15$")
# нет цикла — нет зависания
```

<sub>Кстати, во втором условие стоило писать `age > 3`, т.к. случай с `age == 3` уже рассмотрен первым условием</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что цикл требуется для требования ввода возраста. Тогда:

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input('What is your age?\n'))
        if age <= 3:
            print("price: 0$")
        elif age > 3 and age <= 12:
            print("price: 10$")
        elif age > 12:
             print("price: 15$")
        break
    except:
        print('Please input integer Age!')
```

Comment: Как по мне, лучше все эти if/elif вообще вынести из-под цикла в конец программы.

Comment: @GrAnd, согласен, можно.